# Odd spacing issue in SSRS Chart Legend

Tags: reporting-services, charts, legend

The below image is the legend for my chart. For whatever reason, there seems to be random spacing added in after the 4th category. The text for the legend is:

```
=Fields!categoryHere.Value + " Rate"
```

[image: Spacing isssue]

Has anyone else seen this before?

Appears to work fine in another instance.. (I've only added historical rate back in to show that it works with more items in the legend.)
[image: Working legend]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason the dataset was returning a space (or more?) for that specific category.